# Jeep engine issue

Tags: engine, jeep, stall, liberty, backfire

I have a 2003 Jeep Liberty.

It backfired really loud this morning and now when I try to start it it runs for about 2-3 seconds at 6,000 RPM's and  dies.

Does anyone have any theory's as to why this might happen?

How can a backfire create a situation like this?

Is the backfire a symptom of a larger problem or is it the problem?

Comment: Is the check engine light on now? If so, get the codes read.

Comment: running at 6000 RPM sounds like a big vacuum leak somewhere.  Backfire might had blown something off.